# Middleware внутри другого Middleware в ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Пишу свой middleware для ExpressJS и столкнулся с задачей, где нужно использовать куки. Для этого существует отдельный middleware - [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser). Однако я пока лишь вижу примеры того, как его использовать непосредственно в приложении. Просто импортировать функцию и передать в неё `req` нельзя. Мой код на expressjs выглядит так:

```
export function(params) {
    // здесь производится merge и валидация настроек моего middleware

    return function(req, res, next) {
        // тут уже логика самого middleware
        // и тут нужно прочитать куки
        // но я не знаю как здесь использовать cookie-parser
        // у меня нет app и я не могу сделать app.use(cookieParser())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно куки в конечном итоге нужны всем или большинству мидлварей, так что проще таки добавить вызов cookieparser в самое начало и не заморачиваться.

Но если очень надо, то express в качестве мидлвари умеет принимать массив (везде или почти везде), так что в вашем случае достаточно сделать так:

```
export function(params) {
    // здесь производится merge и валидация настроек моего middleware

    return [ cookieparser(), function(req, res, next) {
        // тут уже логика самого middleware
        // и тут нужно прочитать куки
        // но я не знаю как здесь использовать cookie-parser
        // у меня нет app и я не могу сделать app.use(cookieParser())
    } ];
}
```

Впрочем, в вашем случае так же можно просто взять модуль [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) и вызвать метод parse самостоятельно